# Trigger insert deleted row

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hello I have some difficulties with simple trigger in MSSQL 2008.

I want to insert deleted row to another table.

Here is my trigger code:

```
use databasex;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteEmployee
ON Employees
 FOR DELETE 
AS
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DeletedEmployees (Name, Surname, Function) 
    VALUES (deleted.Name, deleted.Surname, deleted.Function)
 END
```

Employees table:

```
 Name  Surname Function ...
```

DeletedEmployees table:

```
Name Surname Function ...
```

I need somehow to specify that deleted columns are from deleted table, but how ?

I dont want to write subquery for every column.

How it being done ?

ps: is there any good tutorial on using triggers ? i believe i will need write more triggers in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DELETED` is a virtual table you select from (you may have deleted more than one row, so a single value is not enough)

Also, `FUNCTION` is a reserved word and needs to be escaped

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteEmployee
ON Employees
 FOR DELETE 
AS
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DeletedEmployees (Name, Surname, [Function]) 
      SELECT Name, Surname, [Function] FROM deleted
 END
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1654/1).